# PostgreSQL - query all multidigit numbers with repeating digits identical (repdigit, "Schnapszahl")

Tags: regex, postgresql, numbers, string-function

I only want to have the entries with the marked numbers

1234

**11**9834**55**

6526347

**11**

207**555**

**777**

34**3333**987

34678

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regular expression seems to do it:

```
select nr
from numbers
where nr::text ~ '([0-9])(\1)';
```

`([0-9])` creates a group for a single digit. `(\1)` references the first group in the regex. So `([0-9])(\1)` means: "*a digit followed by the same value*"

Output for your sample data is:

```
with numbers (nr) as (
  values 
    (1234),(11983455),(6526347),(11),(207555),(777),(343333987),(34678)
)
select nr
from numbers
where nr::text ~ '([0-9])(\1)';

nr       
---------
 11983455
       11
   207555
      777
343333987
```

---

<sup>Although I only consider 11 and 777 to be a "Schnapszahl"</sup>

Comment: Can you give a short explanation for the regex ([0-9])(\1)!?